# MySQL sum a column based on another distinct column count

Tags: mysql

I need to get sum of `hits` based on distinct `ip`

So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `total`, 
SUM(`hits`) AS `sum` 
FROM `stats`.`stats` 
WHERE `category`=? 
GROUP BY `date`
```

Sample data:

```
|  category |  ip   |  hits  |  date   |
|  11       |  ip1  |  1000  |  date1  |
|  11       |  ip2  |  1000  |  date1  |
|  11       |  ip3  |  1000  |  date1  |
|  11       |  ip4  |  1000  |  date1  |
|  11       |  ip1  |  1000  |  date1  |
```

Expected results:

```
ip=4
sum=4000
```

I am getting as

```
ip=4
sum=5000
```

But this is giving total ip hits instead if summing only distinct ip hits.

Please suggest a way to do this. I would prefer doing something like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN `ip` THAN `hits`)
//or
SUM(CASE WHEN IN(`ip`) THAN `hits`)
//or
SUM(CASE WHEN IF(`ip`) THAN `hits`)
```

instead of subquery as I need fast query.
Also using `array_unique` PHP side will be good for me.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data??

Comment: What do you mean by "summing only distinct ip hits"? How is that different from counting the distinct IPs that hit the site?

Comment: @Ullas check updates in question for sample data

Comment: @Barmar "summing only distinct ip hits" I mean I want to count `DISTINCT ip` first then SUM their `hits`

Comment: What should happen if the two rows for `ip1` have different numbers of hits? Which hit count should be put into the sum? Why are there two rows for the same IP in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar if the two rows for `ip1` have different numbers of hits then the first in ASC order should get counted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT count(s.ip) as cntIp,sum(s.hits) as sumHits 
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.ip,t.hits
    FROM YourTable t) s
```

But it looks like the data you provided is not accurate, I see that you group by date, which means that the date equals and not like in your example date1,date2,date3...

So:

```
SELECT s.date,count(s.ip) as cntIp,sum(s.hits) as sumHits 
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.ip,t.hits,t.date
    FROM YourTable t) s
GROUP BY s.date
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT s.date,count(s.ip) as cntIp,sum(s.hits) as sumHits 
FROM(
    SELECT t.ip,t.hits,t.date
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY t.ip,t.hits,t.date) s
GROUP BY s.date
```

Comment: Corrected question also can I do it without subquery?

Comment: @tallboy not that I can think of, but the second query should work perfectly

Comment: Can it be done using `CASE WHEN` instead of subquery

Comment: Nope sorry, thats your best solution @TallboY

Comment: I think to use array_unique in some way to do this.

Comment: @TallboY I doubt there is any solution that can be done with out a subquery or a join(you want a join solution?) Anyways, whats wrong with having a subquery?

Comment: with subquery query will be very slow for more than 1 Million row

Comment: Not necessarly, depends on the operations used. If you have proper index this query shouldn't take long even with 10 milion rows. Try the solution with group by instead of distinct @TallboY

Comment: If you group by all the columns you select, it's the same as distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a subquery that returns the minimum hit value for each ip/date. Then you can sum these.

```
SELECT date, count(*) as sum, sum(minhits) as hits 
FROM(
    SELECT ip, date, MIN(hits) AS minhits
    FROM stats
    WHERE category = ?
    GROUP BY ip, date) AS subquery
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT 
    `ip`
    COUNT(`ip`) AS `total`, 
    SUM(`hits`) AS `sum` 
FROM 
    `stats`.`stats` 
WHERE 
    `category`=? 
GROUP BY        
    `date`,
     `ip`
```

Comment: Same result does not count distinct hits

Comment: So you can try Group By IP first.I think it will work

Comment: I need group by day first, then check ip's